# Cordova 6.5.0 fails recording audio using cordova-plugin-media FAILED renaming /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording-1489806941198.3gp

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, media

I'm trying to record audio using **cordova-plugin-media** on Cordova 6.5.0. When I run the method it returns me as 'OK' and calls the success callback function, but when this function tries to get the file, the file doesn't exists.

If I just specify the filename the file is placed at /storage/emulated/0/filename.mp3 but this path is inaccessible to the application. So, when I specify to save using **cordova.file.cacheDirectory** as reference, it fires an error on the background, but in javascript interface, it still calling the success callback function.

Taking a look at logcat, I found something like this:

*E AudioPlayer:     
FAILED renaming /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording-1489806941198.3gp to /data/user/0/com.app/cache/recordedData-23-58cca65df12bf.mp3*

I've been searching around internet and I found similar errors related to Cordova 3.5.0 as being a BUG but I'm using Cordova 6.5.0, may the BUG still happening?

Also I already checked app's privileges and all needed privileges are already granted. For example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I've tried using **cordova.file.dataDirectory** instead **cordova.file.cacheDirectory**, but I still having no success.

Here goes a piece of the code:

```
 audioCtx = new Media(
            cordova.file.cacheDirectory + currentMediaFile,
            uploadMediaCapture
        );
        //console.log("Recording audio.");
        audioCtx.startRecord();
```

Anyone got any clue about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Android can not move the file from /storage to /data
The silly part is that moveFile method does not return false if the files can't be moved therefore the Success callback is still called.

So the solution is to replace cordova.file.cacheDirectory   with  **cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory**  or cordova.file.externalDataDirectory